# Correlation Matrix - tidyr gather v. reshape2 melt

Tags: r, matrix, ggplot2, tidyr, reshape2

I would like to use `ggplot2` to make an upper triangle correlation matrix like [this one](http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/ggplot2-quick-correlation-matrix-heatmap-r-software-and-data-visualization). I can replicate that one just fine, but for some reason I'm stuck on really wanting to convert the `reshape2` functions to `tidyr` ones. I would think that I could use `gather` in place of `melt`, but that is not working.

#### Original Results using `reshape2`

```
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)
mydata <- mtcars[, c(1,3,4,5,6,7)]
cormat <- round(cor(mydata),2)
library(reshape2)
melted_cormat <- melt(cormat)

# Get upper triangle of the correlation matrix
get_upper_tri <- function(cormat){
    cormat[lower.tri(cormat)]<- NA
    return(cormat)
}

upper_tri <- get_upper_tri(cormat)

melted_cormat <- melt(upper_tri, na.rm = TRUE)

ggplot(data = melted_cormat, aes(Var2, Var1, fill = value)) + 
    geom_tile()
```

[image]

#### My attempt at this using `gather` from `tidyr`.

```
library(tidyverse)


#first correlatoin matrix
cor_base <- round(cor(mydata), 2)
#now UT
cor_base[lower.tri(cor_base)] <- NA
cor_tri <- as.data.frame(cor_base) %>% 
    rownames_to_column("Var2") %>% 
    gather(key = Var1, value = value, -Var2, na.rm = TRUE) %>% 
    as.data.frame()

ggplot(data = cor_tri, aes(x = Var2, y = Var1, fill = value)) + 
    geom_tile()
```

[image]

The values are all the same, but some change in order occurred that is making this look wrong. A check of `identical` doesn't return `TRUE` but the values of the two data frames seem to be the same...

```
> identical(cor_tri, melted_cormat)
[1] FALSE
> dim(cor_tri)
[1] 21  3
> dim(melted_cormat)
[1] 21  3
> sum(cor_tri == melted_cormat)
[1] 63
```

Any thoughts on this or should I just go ahead and load `reshape2` to accomplish what I'm going for?

Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Essentially, it is the `factor` and `character` types of *Var1* and *Var2* between the reshape2 and tidyr versions. The former's `melt()` retains factors and order of correlation matrix: `"mpg", "disp", "hp", "drat", "wt", "qsec"` and latter's `tibble:rownames_to_colums()` creates character types in alphabetical order: `"disp", "drat", "hp", "mpg", "qsec", "wt"`. As seen both have different levels affecting plot rendering.

To resolve, consider a `dplyr::mutate` line using `base::factor(rownames(.), ...`) and explicitly define the levels as original arrangement of cor_base's `row.names()`. Also, your *Var1* and *Var2* were reversed.

```
cor_base <- round(cor(mydata), 2)
cor_base[lower.tri(cor_base)] <- NA

cor_tri <- as.data.frame(cor_base) %>% 
  mutate(Var1 = factor(row.names(.), levels=row.names(.))) %>% 
  gather(key = Var2, value = value, -Var1, na.rm = TRUE, factor_key = TRUE) 

ggplot(data = cor_tri, aes(Var2, Var1, fill = value)) + 
  geom_tile()
```

[image: Cor Matrix Plot Output]

---

Also, for you or future readers here is the `base::reshape` version that too resolves above factor level issue:

```
cor_base <- round(cor(mydata), 2)
cor_base[lower.tri(cor_base)] <- NA

cor_base_df <- transform(as.data.frame(cor_base),
                         Var1 = factor(row.names(cor_base), levels=row.names(cor_base)))

cor_long <- subset(reshape(cor_base_df, idvar=c("Var1"), 
                           varying = c(1:(ncol(cor_base_df)-1)), v.names="value",
                           timevar = "Var2", 
                           times = factor(row.names(cor_base), levels=row.names(cor_base)),
                           new.row.names = 1:100,
                           direction = "long"), !is.na(value))

ggplot(data = cor_long, aes(Var2, Var1, fill = value)) + 
  geom_tile()
```